# Mongoid Replication Config causing ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I added Replication to my production part of mongoid as shown below:

```
production:
  hosts:
    - - <%= ENV['MONGO_URL1'] %>:<%= ENV['MONGO_PORT'] %>
    - - <%= ENV['MONGO_URL2'] %>:<%= ENV['MONGO_PORT'] %>
  read: :secondary
  username: <%= ENV['MONGO_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGO_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGO_DATABASE'] %>
  max_retries_on_connection_failure: 10
```

This works in production on Heroku, but locally, it's causing my server to fail at starting giving error:

> ROOT /Users/bashar/rails-projects/my-project
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in
>   `load': syntax error on line 13, col 9:`    - - :' (ArgumentError)
>     from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in
>   `load'    from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.7/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:83:in`
>   block in '    from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `instance_exec'   from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   run'     from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
>   `block in run_initializers'   from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`
>   each'    from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
>   `run_initializers'    from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in`
>   initialize!'     from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in
>   `method_missing'  from
>   /Users/bashar/rails-projects/my-project/config/environment.rb:5:in`
>   '    from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'    from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`block in require'   from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'   from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in`new_constants_in'   from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'    from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`require'    from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in
>   `require_environment!'    from
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in`
>   '    from script/rails:6:in `require'    from
>   script/rails:6:in`'  ~/rails-projects/my-project/ [master]

I'm using
Rails 3.1.3
Mongo 1.6.2
Mongoid 2.4.9
MongoDB version 2.0.2

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You config file should look like following:

```
production:
  hosts:
    - <%= ENV['MONGO_URL1'] %>:<%= ENV['MONGO_PORT'] %>
    - <%= ENV['MONGO_URL2'] %>:<%= ENV['MONGO_PORT'] %>
  read: :secondary
  username: <%= ENV['MONGO_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGO_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGO_DATABASE'] %>
  max_retries_on_connection_failure: 10
```

It would resolved to be:

```
hosts: [ 'host1:port1', 'host2:port2']
```

You need double array when giving host and port as two different things:

```
hosts: [ ['host1', 'port1'], ['host2', 'port2'] ]
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. The one dash did not work for some reason, but I formed the array as you suggested directly and that worked. I am guessing some version support issue in one of my gems

Comment: OK that's odd. It worked locally but then failed in production now. Opposite :/

Comment: @BasharAbdullah Is it possible that your local dev environment doesn't has the same tech stack(gem versions, rails, mongodb etc.) as production and that is causing the issue. I would start by taking a look at the differences and trying to isolate the issue from there.

Comment: Quite possible. Thanks. Doing that